# How do I set the terminal buffer scrollback size?

Tags: terminal, neovim

By default the terminal buffer scrollback size is set to 1024, but that is not enough for me and I would like to change it.

`help terminal` does not explain how to configure this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set scrollback=100000
```

in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`.

Comment: 100000 seems to be the maximum (nvim v0.2.1...) so use -1 if you want more.

Comment: At least now, as of v0.5, I wouldn't use -1 because [it's deliberately not documented and it's counterintuitive](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/9563#issuecomment-459387587): `set scrollback=-1` in your init.vim actually gives you only 10000 scrollback in `:term`. (You'd need to use `autocmd TermOpen * setlocal scrollback=-1`.)

Answer (score 8):

According to `:help terminal-emulator-configuration`, the scrollback buffer size is controlled by the `terminal_scrollback_buffer_size` variable.

For example, add the following to your config to set it globally to the maximum value, as defined in `:help terminal-emulator-configuration`:

```
let g:terminal_scrollback_buffer_size = 100000
```

Comment: This answer is no longer valid for nvim > 0.2.0. See other answer.